# getopts behaving strangely in python

Tags: python, arguments, getopts

I am using getops for args management and for some reason my -s variable is not working.  My code is below, as well as the output I am getting

```
try:
  opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hadsp:v", ["help", "all", "display", "single=", "present="])#, "search="])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
  print(err)
  print "Exiting now, no options entered"
  help()
  sys.exit(2)

if len(opts) == 0:
  print "No options passed"
  help()

print opts
print args

for o, a in opts:
  if o in ("-h", "--help"):
    help()
  elif o in ("-p", "--present"):
    search(a)
  elif o in ("-a", "--all"):
    all_install()
  elif o in ("-s", "--single"):
    if a == '':
      print "crap"
      sys.exit(2)
    single_install(a)
  elif o in ("-d", "--display"):
    display()
  else:
    print "Exiting now, unknown option"
    help()
    sys.exit(2)
```

And the output is

```
[('-s', '')]
['test']
crap
```

when I run the program:

```
python file.py -s test
```

Not sure why this is happening, thanks for any help

Comment: argparse is easier and safe to use,

Comment: There's some cruft at the end of line 2, including an extra paren and square bracket.  Strange the interpreter doesn't complain.

Comment: I think you want to use the argument `hads:p:v` instead of `hadsp:v`.  The colon after the `s` specifies that this switch takes an argument.

Comment: @JuanTomas, there's a `#` on line 2. The stuff at the end is comment

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse

argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argParser.add_argument(
        '-p', '--present', dest='present', help='write help here for this parameter')

args = argParser.parse_args()

if args.present:
    search(a)
```

Sample code to use argparse, which is easier to manage and use
-h (or) --help is inbuilt option for argparse

If you would like to use getopt, please refer to documentation for parsing the options

https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html

```
>>> import getopt
>>> args = '-a -b -cfoo -d bar a1 a2'.split()
>>> args
['-a', '-b', '-cfoo', '-d', 'bar', 'a1', 'a2']
>>> optlist, args = getopt.getopt(args, 'abc:d:')
>>> optlist
[('-a', ''), ('-b', ''), ('-c', 'foo'), ('-d', 'bar')]
>>> args
['a1', 'a2']
```